# If else statement not behaving correctly

Tags: python, micropython, raspberry-pi-pico

I am using a Raspberry Pi Pico-W with MicroPython to build a small temperature alarm.
I have tried to build in some hysteresis however the output is using the upper value not the lower one.

I.e. in the code below alarm 1 switches on at 31 but off again at 30.8

```
from machine import Pin, I2C
import utime as time
from dth import DHT11, InvalidChecksum, InvalidPulseCount
pin = Pin(16, Pin.OUT, Pin.PULL_DOWN)
sensor1 = DHT11(pin)

pwr = Pin(22,Pin.OUT, Pin.PULL_DOWN)
alarm1 = Pin(21,Pin.OUT, Pin.PULL_DOWN)
alarm2 = Pin(20,Pin.OUT, Pin.PULL_DOWN)

alarm1temp = 30
alarm1hum = 60

alarm2temp = 35
alarm2hum = 80

temphys = 1
humhys = 2

temp = 0
hum = 0
retrys = 5
pwr.on()
while True:
    time.sleep(2)
    retrycounter = 0
    while retrycounter <= retrys:
        try:
            new_temp = sensor1.temperature
            new_hum = sensor1.humidity
            temp = new_temp
            hum = new_hum
            break
        except:
            print("Error reading data. Try: "+str(retrycounter))
            time.sleep(1)
            if retrycounter > retrys-1:
                    temp = alarm2temp + 1
            retrycounter += 1
            
            
    print("Temperature: {}".format(temp))
    print("Humidity: {}".format(hum))
    
    if temp >= (alarm1temp+temphys) or hum >= (alarm1hum+humhys):
        alarm1.on()
        print("Alarm 1 On")
    elif temp < alarm1temp or hum < alarm1hum:
        alarm1.off()
        print("Alarm 1 Off")
        
    if temp >= (alarm2temp+temphys) or hum >= (alarm2hum+humhys):
        alarm2.on()
        print("Alarm 2 On")
    elif temp < alarm2temp or hum < alarm2hum:
        alarm2.off()
        print("Alarm 2 Off")
```

Comment: you should print the temperature and humidity values when the alarm turns on and off. The alarm switch depends on two conditions, so you need to know both values to understand the behavior

Comment: Try debugging your code. I see you already have `print`s for temperature and humidity, but add similar prints for all the other values as well (`alarm1temp+temphys`, `alarm1hum+humsys`, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the humidity is below the alarm threshold, so this section will reset `alarm1`, as soon as the temperature drops below `alarm1temp+temphys` (and therefore the initial `if` is false)

```
elif temp < alarm1temp or hum < alarm1hum:
    alarm1.off()
    print("Alarm 1 Off")
```

Changing the `or` to `and` should fix it.

TL;DR: You need either thing to be true to set the alarm, but *both* to be false to clear it.